# How to have different colors on top and bottom of SafeAreaView with Iphone X

Tags: react-native, iphone-x

This question [was already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52458846/1731473), but the proposed solution is not working anymore:

```js
return (
  <Fragment>
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex:0, backgroundColor: 'red' }} />
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex:1, backgroundColor: 'gray' }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  </Fragment>
);
```

Should give me:

[image]

Gave me instead:

[image]

As you can see, the view order is not the same.

I have the same issue on iOS.

I am using react `16.13.1`, maybe something changed since the last answer?

What are my alternatives?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me, using React 16.13.1:

```js
return (
        <Fragment>
            <SafeAreaView style={{flex: Platform.OS === "android" ? 0.03 : 0, backgroundColor: "red"}}/>
            <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white"}}/>
            <SafeAreaView style={{flex: Platform.OS === "android" ? 0.03 : 0, backgroundColor: "gray"}}/>
        </Fragment>
    );
```

iOS screenshot:

[image: ios]

Android screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Interesting. So it's maybe something else, I'll keep digging on that. Thanks!

Comment: I did not notice your code is not the same as mine... why 0.03 flex property on android?

Comment: Ya, I added flex to android SafeAreaView components and I also am not wrapping the view in the 2nd SafeAreaView. On Android, the SafeAreaView's were not displaying at all with your original code for me. I had to tell them to take up space by using flex. Not the cleanest approach, but it will work if you can't find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my experiences, `StatusBar` from `react-native` worked well for me.
Example:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';

return (<Fragment>
    <StatusBar
        backgroundColor="#f00"
        barStyle="light-content"
    />
<Fragment>);
```

Cheers.